# A column is named 'primary', how can I do a join with this reserved word?

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2, reserved-words

There is a view column named primary. How can I use this reserved word in a join?

My join:

```
inner join ACCOUNTS
on VIEWX.primary = ACCOUNTS.n_primary
```

I have tried aliasing the column in a select like this:

```
SELECT PRIMARY AS P
```

but that didn't work. The inner join still throws an error.

Comment: Surround it with square brackets: `inner join ACCOUNTS on VIEWX.[primary] = ACCOUNTS.n_primary`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL Server uses brackets to escape reserved words

```
inner join ACCOUNTS on VIEWX.[primary] = ACCOUNTS.n_primary
```